# Recursively sum of an array

Tags: java, recursion

I have a program that I'm trying to make a class for adding array integer from 2 to 100 with an increment of 2 and using recursion. The answer should be the summation of 2 to 100 with an increment of 2 (2+4+6+....+100);

Here is my program looks like so far:

```
public class ArraysInDepth {
public static void main(String[]args){
int size, sum;      
int[] array = new int [101];

sum = sum(array,2);   
System.out.println("The sum of the numbers are " +sum);
}     
public static int sum(int[] arr,int index){


int sumOfNumbers=0;    
arr[index] = index;
sumOfNumbers = sumOfNumbers + arr[index];


enter code here


if(index<arr.length)
{     
sumOfNumbers = sum(arr,index); 


index += 2;   
return sumOfNumbers; 

}

else{
return 0; 
}

}


}
```

But I am getting error every time. And I can not run it. The answer should be the summation of 2 to 100 with an increment of 2 (2+4+6+....+100); Please help me someone. I am in lot of trouble. Thank you.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: try this code if(index<arr.length)
{     
return sumOfNumbers+sum(arr,index+2); 
}  //In main call sum(array,0)

Comment: Oh thank you very much. It will be very much helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is now, your are returning a value `arr[index]` at every depth, without summing anything. Your algorithm should look something like this:

```
public int sum(int[] arr, int index) {
    if(/*index is still valid*/) {
        return arr[index] + sum(arr, index+2);
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much. It will be very much helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion will not stop. You must increase index before call the `sum` recursively.
The most thing of using recursion, is to pay attention to the terminate point.

```
    public class ArraysInDepth {
       public static void main(String[] args){
            int size, sum;      
            int[] array = new int [101];
            sum = sum(array,2);   
            System.out.println("The sum of the numbers are " +sum);
       }     

       public static int sum(int[] arr,int index){   
            if(index<arr.length){        
                 arr[index] = index;
                 int sumOfNumbers = arr[index];
                 index += 2;
                 sumOfNumbers += sum(arr,index); 
                 return sumOfNumbers; 
            }
            else{
                 return 0; 
            }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add, initialize value of the array, and then sum 2+4+……+100 will be better.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. It will be very much helpful to me.